# DirCopy() Not Working

Tags: autoit

I'm working in AutoIT to script a basic task I'll have to repeat on 50ish workstations.

I need to copy a directory and it's subdirectories and files (recursively) to a network share as a backup. For some reason, `DirCopy()` does not work at all.

I've tried running it on several different directories (thinking permissions issue, I'm Domain Admin account), tried doing a RunAs (again thinking permissions), and also put the `#RequireAdmin` tag to force the program to run on an elevated account. Nothing has worked. I can't even get it to copy empty directories.

```
DirCopy(@DesktopDir & "\SAMPLE\TEST1", @DesktopDir & "\SAMPLE\TEST2", 0)
```

Please advise!

Comment: Does it work if you run something like `mkdir SAMPLE\TEST2 & copy /Y SAMPLE\TEST1\* SAMPLE\TEST2`? If not then what is the error message?

Comment: I got this working (sort of), see my "answer" below. Is this the expected functionality of `DirCopy()` ? From the docs, it seems to indicate it should work as I had expected, but in my testing it will only work if the destination directory has not already been created (allowing `DirCopy()` to create it at runtime).

Comment: it seems to work ok if you set the overwrite flag to `1`. You are right that the wording implies that if the directory does exist, then it is not an issue.

Comment: Hmm... thanks. I need it to be set to `0` as it's backing up all 50ish workstations to a single network share in a single directory... now I have to go through the hassle of having it create a new subdirectory for each backup, etc. Gah...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this one out.

Turns out `DirCopy()` is a pretty stupid function that cannot handle if the destination directory already exists (it wants to create it for you). So if you kill the destination directory, then run the above code line, all woks as expected. But then if you add a new file into the source directory (TEST1 in my example), then it breaks again and does nothing.

Go figure...

Now time to find a work-around using something like xcopy...

Comment: Wow, I've been using AutoIt for the first time for like two minutes, I hope is not always this bad. Thanks for taking the time to auto answer.

Comment: Oh snap! Been working with AutoIt for a while but had never used `DirCopy` before. _"Turns out DirCopy() is a pretty stupid function that cannot handle if the destination directory already exists"_ ... I think it's even worse. It won't create the copied directory at all unless you name the target directory explicitly! E.g.  `DirCopy($someDirPath, @DesktopDir)` just doesn't work, not even an error is set. If you append a name for the target directory it works. :|